# estimate transfer function of stepper motor?

Tags: control

I have a stepper motor which has an internal controller. 
I would like to determine them both, but don't know how i should approach the problem. 
the system receives a input velocity and position, and moves toward that position using that velocity. The input could also just be a velocity.

The plant is a Pan and tilt unit, which has 2 stepper motors. I Tried with ident but only got a fit of 5 %...  My input was a noisy signal, and output  was the position it writes out.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I would like to determine them both"?  Please add more details to your question.

Comment: By both i mean I am not able to separate them.. I know they exist so for me   the plant consist of the PTU unit and the controller it is born with.